# In Django, optimize performance when using a foreign key's attribute in the __str__method

Tags: django, django-models

The implementation of DocumentDetail's **str** method works, but is slows everything down by running a bunch of extra queries when I try to use it views, forms, etc. Does anyone know a way around this?

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class DocumentDetail(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document.description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the `DocumentDetail` with the `Document`. You can do this with [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Indeed, we can for example load the `DocumentDetail` and load the document itself together with the `DocumentDetail`s with:

```
DocumentDetail.objects.select_related('document').get(pk=1)
```

This will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and thus load both the `DocumentDetail` and the `Document` in the same query.

We can also fetch *all* `DocumentDetail`s with the related `Document`s with:

```
DocumentDetail.objects.select_related('document')  # all DocumentDetails
```

In views/modelviewsets, etc. where you need to call `str(…)` on the `DocumentDetail`, you thus should rewrite the queries to load the related `Document` in the same query.

Comment: That makes sense. What if I'm trying to use that field in model form. I wonder how I would implement the select_related logic there.